# Best way to show more than 3 tabs on one single mobile screen?

Tags: website-design, ux-field, ux-designer

[image]

Whats the best way to show more than 3 tabs on one single mobile screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the sliding tabs Design pattern. Consider checking out http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html for more information.

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to not use tabs given the limited horizontal real estate. Instead, consider a different UI to accomodate the sections of content. Perhaps accordions or [Miller Columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns).